# SQLite Mismatch error in binding value

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Here is the Sqlite query which I am binding with integer values:

Id is of integer type in the table.

```
SELECT Id, FName,SortString, 1 as OrderStr
FROM CTable 
WHERE ? = Id AND SortString glob '[A-Z]*'      
UNION 
SELECT Id, FName,SortString, 2 as OrderStr
FROM CTable 
WHERE ? = Id AND SortString NOT glob '[A-Z]*' 
ORDER BY OrderStr, FName DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

sqlite3_stmt* c_list_x = NULL;
sqlite3_prepare_v2 is successful. Now when I am binding as below:

```
int Id = 1;

sqlite3_bind_int( c_list_x ,1, Id);
sqlite3_bind_int( c_list_x ,2, Id);
```

int result = sqlite3_step(c_list_x );

result is 20 (SQLite Mismatch: Data type Mismatch)

Why I am getting this even after binding integer value?
Can anyone help me get the result I want?

Comment: Why are you comparing an integer to a string?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did not get you. Where I am comparing string to a Int ?

Comment: I even tried  casting : sqlite3_bind_int( c_list_x ,1, static_cast<int>(Id)); but no luck.

Comment: How is your `CTable` defined?

Comment: @dan04 In CTable 'Id' is Integer and it is not unique. FName, SortString are TEXT.

Comment: Show the table definition. Is this the entire query?

Comment: When I do hard code like "...WHERE '1' = Id.." It is working but I need it to be variable.

Comment: @CL Yes this is complete in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved ! LIMIT and OFFSET values were missed during binding.
Thanks :)